# Getting error while trying spin up old IRI

Tags: seed, iri-node

I need to find old adressed and transactions and therefore i am trying to launch old IRI versions and connect to them using nostalgia.html, but i get this error after entereing the seed. Any idea?

> IRI 1.1.0 
>   Latest milestone has changed from #0 to #6000
>
> Latest SOLID
>   SUBTANGLE milestone has changed from #0 to #6000
>   javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call undefined in
>    at line number 1   at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:586)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:570)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:525)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:521)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:192)
>     at
>   javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
>     at iri.API$Request.process(API.java:167)    at
>   iri.API$Request$1.completed(API.java:112)     at
>   iri.API$Request$1.completed(API.java:84)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:157)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:553)
>     at
>   sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:276)
>     at
>   sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:297)
>     at
>   java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(AsynchronousSocketChannel.java:420)
>     at iri.API$Request.(API.java:84)  at
>   iri.API$1.completed(API.java:35)  at iri.API$1.completed(API.java:28)
>     at sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:126)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Invoker$2.run(Invoker.java:218)    at
>   sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: :1
>   TypeError: Cannot call undefined  at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:58)     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:214)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:186)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.typeError(ECMAErrors.java:173)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.lookupTypeError(Undefined.java:128)
>     at jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Undefined.lookup(Undefined.java:100)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.linker.NashornLinker.getGuardedInvocation(NashornLinker.java:98)
>     at
>   jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeTypeBasedGuardingDynamicLinker.java:176)
>     at
>   jdk.internal.dynalink.support.CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.getGuardedInvocation(CompositeGuardingDynamicLinker.java:124)
>     at
>   jdk.internal.dynalink.support.LinkerServicesImpl.getGuardedInvocation(LinkerServicesImpl.java:144)
>     at jdk.internal.dynalink.DynamicLinker.relink(DynamicLinker.java:232)
>     at jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$\^eval_.runScript(:1)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:535)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:209)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:378)
>     at
>   jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:568)
>     ... 22 more

Comment: Where did you get 1.1.0 from? The earliest I can find on Github is 1.1.0.1 and that one does not have iri.API class (only iri.service.API), so the stacktrace cannot be from that one.

Comment: If there are any subdirs in the ixi dir, try to moving them to another location (away from iri). Because those ECMAErrors point to JavaScript errors, and JavaScript scripts are in the ixi dir.